# Can the Asp.Net Core Data Protection System detect the configuration has changed and generate a new key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, dpapi

I'm creating a new asp.net core 2 website that's using data protection as per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x). As a first pass I created this without protecting the keys (since we're not in production yet) e.g.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"));
}
```

As expected this generated unprotected keys in our test environment. Next, I added the `ProtectKeysWithCertificate` extension so that all newly generated keys are encrypted e.g.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"))
        .ProtectKeysWithCertificate("thumbprint");
}
```

The problem I have however is exactly that ... it's only encrypting *new* keys. It's happily using the original non-encrypted key as it's never been revoked and it's expiry is months in the future.

Is there a way for asp.net to detect that the configuration of Data Protection has changed and for it to generate a new key?

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-immutability) suggests that if we need settings to kick in before the scheduled rolling time  to make a call to `IKeyManager.CreateNewKey` but I don't want that to happen every time the app starts.

As I said this hasn't gone to production yet so I do have the fall back option of manually removing the keys from our test environment but am curious to know if there is another way.

Comment: More an idea than an answer: if you used a new random Guid for the application name on startup (`.SetApplicationName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString)`), shouldn't that trigger new keys every time?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ... in this case I can't do that. Eventually we will be sharing the auth cookie so the other site would need to know the same Guid.